# How to set JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently working on a Box and Whisker Plot project in which the data is from a PHP file and then transferred to javascript function to generate the Box and Whisker Plot. I have here a source on how to generate data but from a random number ranging from 0-15:

```
 var offset = Math.random()*3/4;
 var data = pv.range(0,15).map(function(i) {
     return offset + Math.random()/4;}).sort();
```

How would I output my JSON converted data to this javascript file? I am thinking to change the var data into:

```
var data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4]]
```

But this one does not work. How would I do it? Thank you.

Comment: What does JSON have to do with this?  It sounds like you are talking about building a javascript array/object literal. What do you mean when you say you want to output the array to a javascript file? Typically javascript files are static content.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you're getting data from a php file, why would you set data to the above array?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var jsonArr = {
    data:[]
              };
jsonArr.data.push(new Array(1,2,3,4,5));
jsonArr.data.push(new Array(3,4,2,1));
alert(jsonArr);
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
```

If you want to convert your javascript object to a json string, use JSON.stringify(yourObject);